# Avoiding Concurrency in Windows Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, concurrency

I have developed a windows application for a pharmacy company.So every user can install the set up and use the application.Now there is a Purchase module where user enters InvoiceNumber which should be unique.While entering the InvoiceNumber (and leave text-box) i have a validation to check if the InvoiceNumber already exists.This is fine.Now the problem is if two users are entering the same InvoiceNumber in different systems and when they Click on Save button at the same time, then it will be like inserting two  records with Same InvoiceNumber . This is the problem in 2-3 modules where i can notice the above scenario.

Can anyone advise on avoiding the above scenarios.

As per the below comments If I create Unique Constraint on InvoiceNumber column then it should be unique.In my application user can delete the Created Invoice and again enter those details.In that Case I am just updating the IsDeleted column in Database and this constraint will not work.

Prathap

Comment: How do you save? If you use sql you could just use an identity column for the number.

Comment: Are you using a Database? With primary key and unique identifier on table you solved your problem :)

Comment: Is this data stored in a database?  If so, you'd want to put a unique constraint on the *invoice number* column, then trap the error if it's violated.

Comment: If `InvoiceNumber` is unique, have YOUR APPLICATION fill that data instead of making the END USER do it manually.

Comment: There is one more scenario.What if I delete the record and update the IsDeleted column to 1 and again enter the Same InvoiceNumber.In this case will it work ??

Comment: @HighCore There may be business requirements that dictate the end user must enter the value.

Comment: @Andy If that is the case then the design doesn't seem to robust.  How is the user supposed to know the number?  Are the invoices from another system?  If so and their are duplicates - what then?  If this is a new invoice for the current system - it should be autogenerated.

Comment: @Geek - We will receive Invoices from the Vendor with a unique InvoiceNumber so we cannot autogenerate it.

Comment: @Geek I don't know the OPs specific requirements, but in the past I've had to deal with this as well.  Normally they come in from an outside source. How to handle duplicates (or not) is also typically part of the requirements.  My point is telling the OP that the design is wrong b/c the application should generate is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Andy agreed.  For the OP - you will need to add error handling around your attempted insert statement and provide feedback to the user that the invoice already exists in the system.  You can even go further and prompt them to update the existing one as well as showing what changes will be applied (side by side comparison).

Answer (score 1):

For your update the easiest solution is add a new column `DeletedGuid` of type  `uniqueidentifier` with the constraint `NOT NULL` and have it default to the zero GUID.

When you set `IsDeleted = 1` you also do `DeletedGuid = NewId()`. You then make your unique constraint over `InvoiceNumber, DeletedGuid` instead of just `InvoiceNumber`, by doing that the only way to have duplicate `InvoiceNumber`'s is if one or both values have a random GUID in the `DeletedGuid` column (If you can "undelete" a invoice, be sure to zero out the GUID too).

Comment: If you are willing to modify your code more I would reccomend dropping the `IsDeleted` column completely and replace it with a `row.DeletedGuid != Guid.Empty` test in your code (or leave it but make `IsDeleted` a calculated column if the Sql engine you are using supports it)

Comment: Few users already started using the system..where only user enters the data.So i cannot drop the IsDeleted column now.and even for the existing data if I implement your solution, I need to update the DeletedGuid with a unique number

Comment: Make the column, run `update MyTable set DeletedGuid = NewId() where IsDeleted = 1`, add your constraints. (I am using Microsoft Sql Server syntax, if you are using something else you will need to use the correct update query). You will need to either push out a update to the client or add a Sql Trigger to set the GUID on any opration that set `IsDeleted` to `1` and clear the GUID on any operation that sets `IsDeleted` to `0` to keep the column up to date in the future.

Comment: I am using SqlServer 2005.Once a Invoice is deleted they cannot recall it.Only way is to generate the Invoice again.Thank you scott. Will implement it.

Comment: Scott..i was just thinking..even if I implement this..how will it help in avoiding Duplicates.For example 2users entered InvoiceNumber - 123 and saved it then as the Constraint is on InvoiceNumber and DeletedGuid which will alwasys be unique so two records will be inserted.Am i right ??

Comment: No, because you set the default value of DeletedGuid to be the zero guid both people will attempt to insert `123, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` The unique constraint will prevent the slower user inserting and you will need to handle the error it will generate in your program (like display a friendly dialog saying the invoice number already exists).

Comment: 1) Create a UniqueIdentifier column with default zero.2)If i delete that invoice i also need to update the deletedguid column(becos if they reenter again it InvoiceNumber + DeletedGUid should be unique.....Perfect while two users  insert the same Data.During Updating the Invoice like changing InvoiceDate at the same time.Then  in the where condition I need to mention InvoiceNumber and DeletedGuid which is unique.So this is what I understand Scott.I would just like to confirm if my understading is correct so that I can go ahead and implement.

Comment: Well if you want to protect against people editing fields at the same time you need to implement a lot more than that. You need to fully implement some form of [Optimistic Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I was just showing you how protect against duplicate inserts, this does no protection against concurrent edits. I recommend you go do research on Optimistic Concurrency and then ask a new question on the parts you do not understand.

Comment: I have done some research on Optimistic concurrency.Now what I understand is while Inserting data I need to implement the Solution you recommended(i.e guid()) and for updation Optimistic concurrency will be useful.I am using enterprise library for my application.Will check for the rowupdating event in Enterprise library and how to implement it.

Comment: let me know if I am correct with this approach ...or implementing Optimistic concurrency will solve both Insertion/updation issues??

Comment: You will probably need to use both the guid check and optimistic concurrency, but check your frameworks documentation.